# Adding a file during build with setuptools

Tags: python, package, setuptools

Is it possible to get setuptools.setup() to create a file in the built package, during the build, which is not actually present in the source it's building from?

*edited after advice:* in a generic sense I think there are three fundamental questions I don't understand about setuptools:

1. Is there a temporary build directory?
2. Is the path to that exposed when setup() is called?
3. What is the standard way to hook a Python function into the setup() call?

Comment: Sure it is, but you'll need to provide context of what you are trying to do for answers to be made. There are several ways to do this, depending on the task, like native extension compilation, entry scripts etc. Question needs refining.

Comment: All I want to do is to insert a revision control system ID into a file. The way I do this at the moment is to just have a function called from setup.py which creates this file in the source tree, but it seems better to me if it only existed in the package, so it can't accidently get committed.

Comment: Then you should edit your question with that :) There are existing solutions for versions in python packages, like versioneer (https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer) which is very good and works out of the box. To DIY you will need to write a lot of code that has already been written to avoid circular dependencies with controlling the version string in the file, the version string in setup.py etc.

Comment: There are indeed loads of solutions for version strings in python packaging; I can't believe something so fundamental appears to be made so hard by Python's packaging system. Anyway, the question was intended to be more generic although maybe there are three fundamental questions so I've edited it with that.

Comment: It's not really the packaging system, it's the fact that as python is an interpreted language, code in setup.py is actually executed when the package is installed (there are exceptions to this too). So something in setup.py which modifies source will need to do it in a way that does not break the package or create cyclical dependencies. Again, you should ask a specific question to the problem you are trying to solve and what you have tried so far. The question is still too general. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve